# BigQuery Fails to parse an avro shcema file

Tags: google-bigquery, avro

I need to create an empty table using avro schema file into Google's big query but fails to do so...

I have composed the following sample schema file

```
{
   "namespace": "tutorialspoint.com",
   "type": "record",
   "name": "emp",
   "fields": [
      {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
      {"name": "address", "type": "string"}
   ]
}
```

And the using BigQuery console fails to create a table with the following error:

**Error while reading data, error message: The Apache Avro library failed to parse the header with the following error: Invalid data file. Magic does not match: /subrange//bigstore/bigquery-prod-upload-us**

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery supports loading Avro files, as defined [here](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.9.0/spec.html#Object+Container+Files). There's no formal definition of avro schema file and thus not supported in BigQuery. If you want to create an empty table in BigQuery with schema, you can use a [BigQuery JSON schema file](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#specifying_a_json_schema_file).